# Can access folders through FileStation but not Windows

Tags: network-attached-storage, qnap

NAS : QNAP TS-809U
Version : 4.2.6
Raid6, 8 disks

Hey, because the NAS crashed during an update, I had to "factory reset" it. After solving a lot problems, I'm coming to an end, but there is one last thing not working.

I can't access the NAS and his shared folders through any computers (Windows), it says network path not find. I can however access it with the web interface "File Station". I can read, download or upload files.

Do you have any idea what is causing the issue ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where are many posible reasons of this behavior:

1. check you can ping NAS by name or ip you using to connect web interface. to ensure netbios name working.
2. check if SMB service running on NAS.
3. check if no firewall filters SMB packets.
4. check version of SMB proto you use on NAS. Windows 10 default proto is SMB2.0, maybe your NAS using version 1. If so, you can install SMB1.0 in Win10 - add/remove programs/ installed features.

Comment: I agree, it's probably SMB1 or SMB2 being disabled on the Windows machines.

Comment: @Рамиль Матрасов Thanks for help. Ping is working. SMB is activated on Windows. I'm not sure about SMB on NAS though : I don't have option of SMB in the web interface and when I type in ssh "smb2status" I got an error : "/usr/local/samba/sbin/smbd" ... not found."

Comment: Win/Mac/NFS is SMB in web interface, click advanced, check SMB version.